# Need to change where clause dynamically in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

This is my `Query`:

If I know the BusinessUnitID I have to pass in where clause, Like the Query shown below,

```
select * from tblHRIMS_EmployeeDetail 
where nvrResignedStatus='No' and nvrBusinessUnit= 'BSU-001'
```

Resultant of this query is : 500 Rows

If I dont know the BusinessUnitId I don't need to pass in where clause, Like the Query shown below,

```
select * from tblHRIMS_EmployeeDetail 
where nvrResignedStatus='No'
```

Resultant of this query is : 1500 Rows

How change the `Where` clause dynamically, according to input given.

Note: No need `Stored Procedure`, I need only by Query.

Comment: Which programming language are you implementing this? I can give an idea for this in c# to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure sp-name
@nvrBusinessUnit varchar(50)
as
begin
   select * from tblHRIMS_EmployeeDetail 
   where nvrResignedStatus='No' and nvrBusinessUnit= @nvrBusinessUnit 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @BusinessUnit varchar(50)

select @BusinessUnit = null 
-- or
select @BusinessUnit = 'bsu-001'

select * from tblHRIMS_EmployeeDetail  
where nvrResignedStatus='No' and nvrBusinessUnit= isnull(@BusinessUnit,nvrBusinessUnit)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query is inside a stored procedure, and let's say you have the @nvrBusinessUnit variable you can do:

```
select * from tblHRIMS_EmployeeDetail 
where nvrResignedStatus='No' and nvrBusinessUnit= isnull(@nvrBusinessUnit,nvrBusinessUnit)
```

If this is what you query directly from your application, then you can build the string there.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblHRIMS_EmployeeDetail 
WHERE nvrResignedStatus = 'No'
 AND (@nvrBusinessUnit IS NULL OR nvrBusinessUnit = @nvrBusinessUnit)
```

Comment: It does not working...
No Rows Returned when executed this Query...
In database all records have BusinessUnit so there no chance of Business Unit Being NULL

Comment: @somasundaram, No the `@nvrBusinessUnit` is the parameter you passed to the query not the `nvrBusinessUnit` column, like the value `BSU-001` that you passed in your example. So if you passed the parameter with a `NULL` value it will ignore the AND statement, that's why `AND(@nvrBusinessUnit IS NULL)...`. Try it with a `NULL` value and with non null value.